# How to reduce the runtime for pandas rolling taking too long run on multiple columns - pandas

Tags: time-series, python, pandas

I am working on a `timeseries` data. I am trying to apply the percentage change to the data.

Here is a snapshot of the data:

```
Time                     EX  SC      WH      YE Lt   Ub     Yl_2    Wm      Wm_2    value
2016-02-15 11:54:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.38    755 232 0.009   0.11    1428    1020    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:55:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.38    755 232 0.009   0.111   1436    1018    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:56:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.38    755 232 0.014   0.113   1471    1019    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:57:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.37    755 232 0.015   0.111   1457    1015    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:58:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.38    755 232 0.013   0.111   1476    1019    FALSE
2016-02-15 11:59:00 UTC 4.4 0.14    8.36    755 232 0.013   0.114   1416    1015    FALSE
```

The shape of the data is `(122334, 10)`

Here is my function:

```
def percent_change(series):
    # Collect all *but* the last value of this window, then the final value
    previous_values = series[:-1]
    last_value = series[-1]

    # Calculate the % difference between the last value and the mean of earlier values
    percent_change = (last_value - np.mean(previous_values)) / np.mean(previous_values)
    return percent_change
```

Applying the function here:

```
df2 = df.rolling(10).apply(percent_change)
```

Takes forever, please what am I doing wrong? Or how should I do it instead?

Thanks

Comment: This is better suited for SO, so I'm voting it to be migrated. Note that you're applying the same function to all the columns, including time and boolean columns. Apply function is in general slow, you might get away with rolling mean (quite fast) + percentage calc, in a different column

Comment: You are wasting many cycles by computing the cumulative means over and over again.  This is a $O(n^2)$ algorithm for a series of length $n.$  A cumulative mean can be computed once and for all with a cumulative sum, requiring $O(n)$ time, from which the "percent_change" can be obtained in $O(n)$ time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses `shift()` and `rolling()` to compute the mean efficiently:

```
import pandas as pd

def rolling_pct_change(df, field):
    t = df.copy()
    t['mean'] = t['x'].shift(1).rolling(3).mean()
    t['pct_change'] = ((t['x'] - t['mean']) / t['mean'])
    return t

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [*range(10)]})
df2 = rolling_pct_change(df, 'x')
print(df2)

   x  mean  pct_change
0  0   NaN         NaN
1  1   NaN         NaN
2  2   NaN         NaN
3  3   1.0    2.000000
4  4   2.0    1.000000
5  5   3.0    0.666667
6  6   4.0    0.500000
7  7   5.0    0.400000
8  8   6.0    0.333333
9  9   7.0    0.285714
```